# How to set ext properties inside gradle task and use it outside task and subprojects

Tags: gradle

This is what i am trying inside the gradle task

```
task parse(type: Exec) {
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    executable 'make'
    args "print_JDBC_CURRENT_JDK_OPT_JAR"
    doLast {
        project.ext.jdkver=standardOutput.toString()
    }
}

println project.jdkver
```

> Error: Could not get unknown property 'jdkver' for root project 'xyz'
>   of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

Task actions, `doFirst` and `doLast` closures are executed during *execution phase*, but everything else in your build script, including your `println` statement is executed before that, during the so-called *configuration phase*.

Since the extension property is used before it's defined, the build fails.

If the value you determine is only required in another task, you can keep your approach and use the value in the tasks, if they are executed after this task (which you can ensure via `dependsOn`).

If you need the value in your *configuration phase* and independent from any task (or how you call Gradle), do not use an `Exec` task, but the `exec` method of your `Project` object, which will be executed immediately.

Comment: I am trying to get the jdkversion by executing "MAKE" and set ext property inside gradle task "parse" and use that property in subprojects, Could you please suggest any better options.

Comment: dependsOn works and I generate the properties and set in gradle.properties file through a task how can I access the properties which I set in gradle.properties from a subprojects tasks ?